# Как правильно взять value от input-а и передать в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть текстовой input и button, при нажатии на button, value от inputa должен передаться компонент.
Сейчас при каждом изменении value сохраняется в state, а при нажатии уже передается.
Правильно ли так ? Получается что, при каждом изменении value вызывается callback onChange, а тот вызывает setState...

Answer (score 1):

Привел пример с обоими вариантами. Можете оценить преимущества обоих.

Чтобы не писать в state, вы можете получить значение `input` по его `ref` в момент нажатия кнопки

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       value: '',
       valueOld: '',
       changed: false,
       length: 0
    }
  }
  
  input1Change = (e) => {
    let next = this.state;
    next.value = e.target.value;
    next.changed = next.value !== next.valueOld;
    next.length = e.target.value.length;
    this.setState(next);
  }
  
  button1Click = () => {
    alert(`Кнопка1: Введен текст ${this.state.value}`);
  }
  
  button2Click = () => {
    let text = this.input2.value;
    if(text && text.length > 0) {
      alert(`Кнопка2: Введен текст ${text}`);
    } else {
      alert(`Кнопка2: Ничего не введено`);
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading">Пример со state</div>
            <div className="panel-body">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <div className="input-group">
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="..."
                    ref={ref => this.input1 = ref}
                    onChange={this.input1Change}
                    value={this.state.value}
                  />
                  <span className="input-group-btn">
                    <button 
                      className="btn btn-primary" 
                      type="button"
                      onClick={this.button1Click}
                      disabled={!this.state.changed}
                    >Go!</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
                {this.state.changed &&
                  <p className="text-success">
                    Текст изменен, введено {this.state.length} символов
                  </p>
                }
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="panel panel-default">
          <div className="panel-heading">Пример без state</div>
            <div className="panel-body">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <div className="input-group">
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="..."
                    ref={ref => this.input2 = ref}
                  />
                  <span className="input-group-btn">
                    <button 
                      className="btn btn-primary" 
                      type="button"
                      onClick={this.button2Click}
                    >Go!</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от вашей архитектуры и принципов по которым вы строите свое приложение. Если брать к примеру подход Flux, к архитектуре от facebook https://habr.com/ru/post/246959/ , то основной принцип в вашем случае будет говорить, о том, что компонент должен не чего не знать о стейте, быть чистой функцией и выполнять только то, что приходит по пропсам. Отсюда вывод, что согласно этого подхода к архитектуре, ваш компонент должен отправить данные в стейт и ждать от него команды. Если есть еще и сервер, то отправляем на сервер (но не из компонента), сервер дает добро, связывается с стейтом, стейт присылает новые пропсы